# Create a unique lists of keys with the same value

Tags: javascript, object

I need to scan through multiple objects and form an unique list of keys, which have the same value:

```
var data1={"L1":"X","L2":"X","L1L2Relate":"AND"}
var data2={"L2":"X","L3":"X"}
```

Output - all the keys that have "X" for value.

```
['L1','L2','L3'];
```

I tried with the following code but it is not giving the desired result. Kindly suggest.

```
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
}
for (i =1 ;i<=7;i++)
{
   arr.push(getKeyByValue(data1,'X'));

}
```

Comment: Why is `L1L2Relate` not in your output?

Comment: @NickParsons, I think he wants the unique keys with same values..

Comment: Yes unique value keys.

Comment: What if `data1 = { a: "X" }, data2 = { a: "notX" }`? Add `a` anyways? Btw, downvoting probably stems from the question not clearly formulating the problem. You've got the sample input/output and the "own attempt" parts, but from your text, i for one can't tell what you want. "Form an unique list of keys" just isn't a proper task description for what you seem to actually want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate the objects list (`...objs`) with [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of [key, value] pairs. [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) items that don't have the requested value, and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to an array of keys. Convert to [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) back to an array, to get unique keys.

```js
const fn = (value, ...objs) => 
  [...new Set( // make unique with a Set and convert back to an array
    objs.flatMap(Object.entries) // get an array of entries
      .filter(([, v]) => v === value) // filter according to value
      .map(([k]) => k) // get the keys
  )]

const data1={"L1":"X","L2":"X","L1L2Relate":"AND"}
const data2={"L2":"X","L3":"X"}

const result = fn('X', data1, data2)

console.log(result)
```

More compatible version that uses spread with `Array.concat()` instead of `Array.flatMap()`

```js
const fn = (value, ...objs) => 
  [...new Set( // make unique with a Set and convert back to an array
    [].concat(...objs.map(Object.entries)) // get an array of entries
      .filter(([, v]) => v === value) // filter according to value
      .map(([k]) => k) // get the keys
  )]

const data1={"L1":"X","L2":"X","L1L2Relate":"AND"}
const data2={"L2":"X","L3":"X"}

const result = fn('X', data1, data2)

console.log(result)
```

Another option is to reduce the list of objects to a Set, iterate the entries with `Array.forEach()`, and add to the Set only keys with the request values. Then spread the Set back to an array.

```js
const fn = (value, ...objs) => 
    [...objs.reduce((r, o) => {
      Object.entries(o)
        .forEach(([k ,v]) => {
          if(v === value) r.add(k);
        })
        
    return r;
    }, new Set())]

const data1={"L1":"X","L2":"X","L1L2Relate":"AND"}
const data2={"L2":"X","L3":"X"}

const result = fn('X', data1, data2)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I get UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: objs.flatMap is not a function.I am using it in a node app and its a version 8 due to the server constraints